# Triggering an event in C3.js

Tags: javascript, triggers, click, dom-events, c3.js

I am using C3.js framework to create a chart.

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Banzay/w1narm4u/3/ where if you click on the 'dataOne' link the blue line will disappear from the chart.

What I want to achieve is when any of the 'click me' elements is clicked I want the 'dataOne' click event to be triggered (so the blue line will be hidden).

I have tried:

```
$('.clickme').click(function () {  
    $('.c3-legend-item-event').trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

html -

```
<div class="clickme" onclick="unloadBlue()">click me</div>
```

js -

```
function unloadBlue(){
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'dataOne'
    });
}
```

To reload data, use this in another function

```
chart.load({
    columns: [
        ['dataOne', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250] 
    ]
});
```

This did not work in JsFiddle for me, but does work.
Also, your closing div tag has / at end, should be at front.

[Here's the link to this example.](http://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html)